# Re-render a VariableSizedWrapGrid

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

Once a VariableSizedWrapGrid has rendered its content, is there a way to refresh its layout so that it re-renders and re-applies the sizes if they have changed?

For example, the first item is twice the size of the rest, then I change the column and row span values in the view model. Now I want to invoke the grid to re-render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
public void Update(GridView gridView)
{
    if (!(gridView.ItemsPanelRoot is VariableSizedWrapGrid))
        throw new ArgumentException("ItemsPanel is not VariableSizedWrapGrid");
    foreach (var container in gridView.ItemsPanelRoot.Children.Cast<GridViewItem>())
    {
        var data = container.Content as Common.ModelBase;
        VariableSizedWrapGrid.SetRowSpan(container, data.RowSpan);
        VariableSizedWrapGrid.SetColumnSpan(container, data.ColSpan);
    }
    gridView.ItemsPanelRoot.InvalidateMeasure();
}
```

1. Assuming Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridView as ItemsControl
2. Assuming Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid as ItemPanel

> I integrated it into the custom grid like this: http://codepaste.net/aopvks

Best of luck!